# There is a way to prevent the initial "fall" of sprites in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

Day 3 in Phaser and I'm trying to avoid the initial "fall from the sky" of the assets. 
I initialized it like this:

```
this.kid = this.physics.add.sprite(50, 380, 'idle');
```

but when reload the game, the sprites fall from sky until touch the ground. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a gravity Y set to some positive value.
You can set it to 0 in the `config` to avoid things falling.

```
new Phaser.Game({
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 0 }
        }
    }
})
```

I suggest you to follow the tutorial "[Making your first Phaser 3 game](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part1)".
In part6 there is the part about gravity.